# Skip last line of file perl

Tags: sql, perl, while-loop, increment

I am trying to generate an SQL query using perl based of a dir list.

**DATA**

file_1.csv
file_2.csv
file_3.csv

---

**CODE**

```
$count = 1;
$files = qr/^.*?$/;
print "select id,Network_Location from data where Network_Location like\n";
while (<>)
{
if ( $_ =~ $files ) {
print "'%".$_."%' OR Network_Location like"."\n";
}
$count++;
}
```

**My Results**

select id,Network_Location from data where Network_Location like
'%file_1.csv
%' OR
'%file_2.csv
%' OR
'%file_3.csv%' OR

**Desired Results**

select id,Network_Location from data where Network_Location like
'%file_1.csv%' OR
Network_Location like '%file_2.csv%' OR
Network_Location like '%file_3.csv%'

---

First of all, my "%'" is getting bumped down a line for some reason.  I also do not want to print 'OR' at the end of the last line of the file.  The directory I am parsing may contain hundreds of files.

Any help?  I am guessing it has to do with my '$count' variable but I can't put my finger on it.  As far as "%'" being bumped down a row, I have no idea.

Comment: bump down a line: you need to trim the carriage return off of `$_` with `chomp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$files = qr/^.*?$/;
my @matches;
while (<>)
{
  chomp; # remove end of line characters
  if ( $_ =~ $files ) {
    push @matches, $_; # store match in @matches array
  }
}
if( @matches ) {
   print 
     "select id, Network_Location from data where\n",
     join( " OR\n", map { "Network_Location like '%$_%'" } @matches ),
     "\n";
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly fine for what I need and will more than likely apply to other things as well.  Very clever how you stored the file contents into an array and joined on the SQL OR statement.  So when  using "map", will that modify the contents of the array? @Andrzej A. Filip

Comment: AFAIR `map` leaves input list "as it is" unless you assign something to `$_` - see `perldoc -f map` for details.